# DataTables Editor - remote hosting of code not allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to implement [Datatables](https://editor.datatables.net) with simple inline editing.

I have purchased developer license and am trying to run example given at:
 https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple.html

However, I am getting following error in browser's console:

```
[Error] DataTables Editor - remote hosting of code not allowed. Please see http://editor.datatables.net for details on how to purchase an Editor license or download a trial version of Editor from https://editor.datatables.net/download
(anonymous function) (dataTables.editor.min.js:15:87)
Global Code (dataTables.editor.min.js:18)
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new $.fn.dataTable.Editor')
(anonymous function) (jquery.min.js:2:31697)
```

Could someone please help me out?

P.S.: I can see some similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439821/uncaught-exception-datatables-editor-remote-hosting-of-code-not-allowed), but is not yet answered. Also not sure if that person has purchased license or not.

Comment: Are you linking to the `dataTables.editor.min.js` file on the datatables.net server or similar? Offhand, it sounds like you are linking to a remote file and they want you to download it from your account with them and host it yourself. Just a guess though

Comment: Yep, seems that is indeed the issue: https://datatables.net//forums/discussion/35833

Comment: Thanks for comment but nope, actually I have downloaded all required JS and CSS files and accessing these from my local download location.

Comment: Including the editor files? You certain you got them all? That error seems to pretty specifically point to that  as the issue, there are several posts online explaining that as the cause.